# "Was" vs "has/had" in this sentence

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

I saw a sentence but I am not sure about its tense.

> She **was** to prepare for the spelling test.

I think instead of "was", "has" or "had" is better. I think that "was" is wrongly used here.

Comment: You **are not to play** with this catnip *until* you have done your homework, do you understand?!

Comment: @TRomano: That's interesting! In your context (specifically because of the negation, I'm guessing) *both* verbs imply "obligation" rather than "plan". *You **have** (=**haff**) to not play with it. But there's also *You are to not play with it,* at the margins.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your **plan** or **prearrangement** is fine. The quasi modal use covers a spectrum that ranges from "here's the plan, dude", through "instruction" and  "command" to "the unavoidable".

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/be-to-do-something

Comment: She was to prepare. It think it's related to subjunctive clause

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're both valid, and I don't recall this *specific* distinction being raised on ELL before, so...

> 1: *I **had** to leave at midnight* (where ***had*** is often pronounced ***hat***, see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/pronunciation-of-have-in-i-dont-have-to-do-something) on ELU)
>    I was obliged, **of necessity**, to do so
>
> 2: *I **was** to leave at midnight*
>    It **had been prearranged** (by myself or others) that I would leave at midnight

Perhaps this might make the distinction clearer...

> 3: *I **had** to leave at midnight, but I decided to stay overnight* - INHERENTLY CONTRADICTORY
>    4: *I **was** to leave at midnight, but I decided to stay overnight* - a bit dated / formal, but otherwise fine

---

So in OP's specific context, if *she **was** to prepare for it* then preparing for the test was (hers or someone else's) *plan* (and maybe things *didn't* [go according to plan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go-according-to-plan)), whereas if *she **had** to prepare for it*, she had no choice; she *must* do it, come what may.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your parenthetical note, "where had is pronounced hat"?  I'm a native AmE speaker, and while I know that I pronounce "had" either as "hed" or "had" depending on location (e.g., "He had had too many drinks" would sound like "He hed had..."), I don't follow your note here.  The "had" in "I had to leave at midnight" sounds the same as the "had" in "I had chicken for dinner" to me.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: It was gone into at some length over on ELU several years ago in my own question: [Pronunciation of “have” in “I don't have to” [do something]](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/). At the time of asking I wasn't consciously aware that we do much the same with ***use*** and ***suppose*** (where pronunciation also changes for the "special" meaning). I don't think it's on that specific page, but somewhere one of our top linguists suggested that effectively these are now *different words* that just happen to have the same spelling / etymology as the "originals".

Comment: ...I suppose it's likely even some individual *native* speakers might not be aware of the usage (or might avoid using it themselves even if they hear it from others). And doubtless many *non* native speakers won't know it. But so far as I'm aware, it's pretty standard across the US (which actually has very little dialectal variation), and I'd be surprised if there were any regional dialects in the UK that don't include it. The special pronunciation isn't exactly *obligatory*, but it's certainly at least the norm.

Comment: I'm not unfamiliar with those kind of pronunciation shifts (or different words spelled the same way), but had pronounced as hat in this situation (or any) isn't one I'm aware of. Do you happen to have any geographic regions for it?  As one point of anecdata,  I'm from the northeastern US, and I don't think I pronounce this had as hat.

Comment: @Joshua: As implied by my comments above (and various comments / answers on the ELU question), it's not that this is some kind of regional "dialect". I can't rule out the possibility that where you live has a "regional variation" in that they *don't* honour it, but I think more likely if you asked 100 of your neighbours they mostly *would* know (and use) it. Do you not recognise [your countryman Peter Shor's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/pronunciation-of-have-in-i-dont-have-to-do-something#comment68895_37742) point re ***use**?* What about the "special" ***supposed**?*

Comment: No, that's just it, I *am* aware of those and some others (like prolly or even pry for probably), and that I use those too. I'm a couple hundred miles west of where I grew up, and there are plenty of different pronunciations that I *do* notice (elementTRY/elemenTARY, aunt/ant), and that's why I'm so curious about this one (because it's one I'm *not* familiar with). Trying to use this pronunciation feels strange to me, whereas many of these kinds of observations are easily confirmed, and right away I realize "oh yes, I do that."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Remarkable. I can't remember the last time I heard this usage of _was_ in NAmE speech, even formal speech. I may never have done.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I don't think I'd be likely to use the form in speech often either (if at all - particularly as a past tense). But it could well be dying off faster in AmE that BrE. I get plenty of results on bbc.com from a site-specific search for **"are to meet"** limited to the past week, but the same on nytimes.com returns no hits at all.

Comment: @Joshua: Personally, I'd almost never notice how many syllables someone enunciated in words like *elementary, February, Wednesday*. Just as even if you asked me while I was reading the last page of a book, I couldn't tell you whether it used the ["single story"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A) version of the letter **a** without looking down to check. To a considerable extent, I understand such things as just ***symbols*** - so long as I know *which* symbol it's supposed to be, I don't tend to notice variations unless they carry some extra significance *in and of themselves*.

Comment: I live in New England now but grew up in Indiana — I've never heard "had" shift to "hat". *Maybe* "ha'to", but never an enunciated "hat to".

Comment: @mattdm: I'm surprised at that. Admittedly, ***hafta*** doesn't appear in the title of [How often do people say “gotta”, “wanna” or “gonna” in English speaking countries?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62045/) over on ELU, but that version is mentioned several times in comments and answers, and I don't think anyone on that page (or anywhere else on ELU, so far as I recall) says anything about not having encountered it before (and I'm sure I've never seen ***havta*** in anyone's "eye dialect" representation of the usage).

Comment: Maybe I'm confused. _Hafta_, yes, very common — but "hat to", no. And I don't think I said anything about "hafta" or "havta".

Comment: I see that you are from the UK; I couldn't find much searching online but what I did find (e.g. [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.usage.english/5DJP_vv31II/166pK_RPl9kJ)) all references the UK. An [1896 book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xoc4AQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA61&ots=UDEyv9CywO&dq=%22had%20to%22%20pronunciation%20%22hat%20to%22&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false) suggests "hat to" in New England, or maybe Kentucky — but that's rather dated. I think this may be primarily a BrE thing.

Comment: @mattdm: That sounds even more strange to me. As I said earlier, the ***haff / hat*** versions almost represent a *different word* today, so it seems perfectly natural to me that they should conjugate differently as verbs. I suppose if you know the present tense one but not the corresponding past tense, it's possible people around you simply don't use it, but I'd have thought you could hardly avoid hearing it on radio, TV, movies, and the like. Maybe you just don't *notice* because you're not consciously aware that people *might* say it differently for the "past tense obligation" sense.

Comment: No; like Joshua, I'm really quite certain. I don't doubt that people where you are do it differently.

Comment: @mattdm: Well, I've no idea how to establish the exact extent of the usage, but I'm more or less certain it would turn out to be more accurate to describe things in terms of there being some geographical / sociolinguistic *pockets* where it's ***not*** common, rather than there being just a limited number of places where it ***is*** used.

Comment: Were that the case, I think it would be easier to find reference to it. The only other one I can find is an [1911 book published in California](https://books.google.com/books?id=OGRJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=%22had+to%22+pronunciation+%22hat+to%22&source=bl&ots=SiXKfEL6D1&sig=5CSrI8Mxq6yI55aTQwmzULBWkSc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixzIar_fXOAhUJFx4KHWyECjcQ6AEIPDAG#v=onepage&q&f=false), which notes "hat to" as an error.

Comment: I've been listening to various YouTube videos trying to find examples. "Hadta" is certainly common, as is something somewhat softer, like "ha'ta", but I've not come across a clear "hat ta", let alone "hat to". Do you have an example?

Comment: Huh. Maybe we have a new question, here. :)

Comment: @mattdm: Google doesn't have audio search facilities yet, so no. But I don't understand what I'm trying to achieve here. In *global* terms I'm sure the usage is quite widespread, but if you don't *believe* me it seems rather pointless for me to find instances anyway. If you're not familiar with it, that's just the way things are. The top answer on ELU starts [As an American, I can report that everyone I know, even highly educated people, use these forms several times a day.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/62057/2637), almost all the others say much the same, and I see no dissension there.

Comment: Yes, _gotta_, _wanna_, _gonna_, and _hafta_, but... that answer doesn't say anything about your "hat to". As I said above, "hadta" is the common equivalent. It's probably worth adding that "gotta" is often pronounced "godda" — see for example http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/ive-got-to-do-something

Comment: In fact, the _answer_ you link says that a "d" sound is used! It would be very peculiar, therefore, for an enunciated "t" to be used in hadta.

Comment: @mattdm: That's not how it works. The present tense is ***haff***, which in eye dialect is often represented as *hafta* since this usage only ever occurs before an infinitive starting with ***to*** (invariably reduced to a schwa). The past tense is ***hat***, which is almost never attempted orthographically by non-linguists. Both /t/'s in ***wanna*** are often discarded (as is the one in ***gonna***), but no-one discards "both" in *I had to laugh* (assuming that like me they recognise there *are* two /t/'s, because it's *I **hat to** laugh*). But to repeat - you don't use it, end of story.

Answer (score 5):

*Be to +infinitive* usually means that you are supposed or expected to do something.

> She was to prepare (was supposed to prepare) for the test.

*Have to + infinitive means that the situation doesn't depend on your wishes.

> She had to prepare for the test, she had no choice.

Answer (score 4):

"She ***was*** to prepare for the spelling test".

It certainly can be used like that where it is a special use of "be" called "quasi-modal be".

It has some semantic affinities with the modal auxiliaries in that it is used for deontic necessity where it is comparable to "must". And syntactically it resembles them in that it has only a primary form, as well as having  all the auxiliary properties such as inversion (*was she to prepare for the spelling test?*), a negative form (*She wasn't to prepare for the spelling test*) and so on.

Answer (score -1):

> She was to prepare for the spelling test.

She | was | to prepare | for the spelling test.

"was" is past tense; past tense means an action that started and ended before now. This means that in the past she had an upcoming spelling test. We know this because of the infinitive adjective phrase on the other side of the linking verb "was." The phrase, acting like an adjective, modifies the subject "she" to describe something about her--she had to get ready for a spelling test. She was to prepare for it. The adverb prepositional phrase "for the spelling test" simply modifies "prepare" the infinitive verb in the infinitive phrase.

**Was**. *v*.

d :  to take place :  occur

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be

Answer (score -1):

Another way of looking at it, is that English over time might have dropped a word which would have been there originally, and would make sense:

"She was *[expected/intended/required]* to prepare for..."

I'm not sure if this is historically and  technically correct but it 'feels right'.

The current English usage carries this sense, as if the words in brackets are silently present. Perhaps they once were.